# RequestedScopre ManagedBean VS Stateful Bean

Tags: ejb, managed-bean, stateful-session-bean

How to choose which implementation of UserDao class? One is a stateful session EJB, and the other one is a manged session bean with RequestedScope annotation.

The code of the stateful session seems much simpler. In this user greeter case, both should work?

Also, what's the scope of a stateful EJB?

UserDao.java

```
public interface UserDao {
    User getForUsername(String username);

    void createUser(User user);
 }
```

EJBUserDao.java

```
@Stateful
@Alternative
public class EJBUserDao implements UserDao {

@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;

public User getForUsername(String username) {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username = ?");
        query.setParameter(1, username);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void createUser(User user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
}
}
```

ManagedBeanUserDao.java

```
public class ManagedBeanUserDao implements UserDao {

@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
private UserTransaction utx;

public User getForUsername(String username) {
    try {
        User user;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username = :username");
            query.setParameter("username", username);
            user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            user = null;
        }
        utx.commit();
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (SystemException se) {
            throw new RuntimeException(se);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void createUser(User user) {
    try {
        try {
            utx.begin();
            entityManager.persist(user);
        } finally {
            utx.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (SystemException se) {
            throw new RuntimeException(se);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EJB is simpler just because of using `UserTransaction` in the other bean, nowadays with CDI 1.1 you can do the same in CDI as in your EJB (just annotate the bean or methods with `TransactionAttribute.REQUIRED`).

However you shouldn't mark your DAO bean as Stateful or SessionScoped, DAO is a stateless service by nature so you are probably looking for Stateless or RequestScoped. I would go with plain CDI (if you don't need other EJB features like async calls), it's getting more and more stuff from EJB (for instance transactions) and I guess that those two technologies will get merged eventually.